# How do I get the text value of the selected TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

My code that generates the `TreeView` from the database is working, but now I want to open new window based on the selected `TreeViewItem` but I am not sure how to access the item in my `SelectedItemChanged` event handler.

[image: Compiler error in event handler]

`TreeView` Xaml:

```
<TreeView x:Name="Tree" SelectedItemChanged="Tree_SelectedItemChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding RootNodes}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding rsParentChild}">
            <Grid>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding icon}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock  Name="MenuItem" Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding NodeDescription}"  FontFamily="Humanst521 Lt BT" ></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

The code behind:

```
public Dashboard()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = dbm;
    dbm = (Model.Administration.DashboardModel)FindResource("modVar");

    var dataSet = getData();
    _rootNodes = dataSet.Tables["Table1"].DefaultView;
    _rootNodes.RowFilter = "ParentId IS NULL";
    this.DataContext = this;
}

private DataView _rootNodes;
public DataView RootNodes
{
    get { return _rootNodes; }
}

internal DataSet getData()
{
    DataTable dt = dbm.Menu(dbm, "Menu");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    //add a relationship
    ds.Relations.Add("rsParentChild", ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns["Id"], ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns["ParentId"], false);
    return ds;
} 

private void Tree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<T> e)
{
    string menuitem = MenusItem.text;
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("menuitem");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a handler to the [SelectedItemChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditemchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event?

Comment: yes but it's not work

Comment: Can you explain "not work"? Is your handler not being called? Are you unable to get the information you want from the `TreeViewItem` in the handler?

Comment: Actully it called perfectly when I used  SelectedItemChanged event in my treeview but i got null value in variable when i was using this line(var menuname = MenuItem.String();) or when i was using this line(var menuname = MenuItem.text;) this show error

Comment: I m completely new in this technology so I dont have much idea about it that why it show error here because i have used same line and it works fine but in treeview it show error

Comment: Can you post the code for your handler? In what you have posted in your question you do not have a handler for the `SelectedItemChanged` event.

Comment: i have add SelectedItemChanged my code please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the properties from the event to access the `TreeViewItem` that was selected (or in your case, the `DataRowView`).  I have slightly modified the example from the for [SelectedItemChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditemchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) so that it will match your code.  Notice how the event data contains the `DataRowView` that was selected.  You need to use the event data to get the selected item and then you can do whatever you need to do with the item.

```
private void Tree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e)
{
    var item = (DataRowView) e.NewValue;
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(item["Id"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Show An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Tacto.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem'.

Comment: @KartikPareek - I have updated the solution. I forgot that you are binding a `DataView` and so the item in the event is a `DataRowView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bindable SelectedItem property using WPF [`Behaviors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-4/ff726531(v%3Dexpression.40))

```
public class perTreeViewHelper : Behavior<TreeView>
{
    public object BoundSelectedItem
    {
        get => GetValue(BoundSelectedItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(BoundSelectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundSelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BoundSelectedItem",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(perTreeViewHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                OnBoundSelectedItemChanged));

    private static void OnBoundSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.NewValue is perTreeViewItemViewModelBase item)
            item.IsSelected = true;
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged -= OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object obj, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> args)
    {
        BoundSelectedItem = args.NewValue;
    }
}
```

More details and a wider general discussion TreeViews in WPF on my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/).